# Autodesk AR/VR Toolkit Server v2 Problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk-forge

Since a few weeks, there are some problems using the Autodesk [AR/VR Toolkit](http://forgetoolkit.com/#/).

When we first started using it, **version 3** of the **unity package** was available on the official website linked above. Everything worked fine, it was just very slow to import a scene into unity (10-15 min for a single family home).

When visiting the Autodesk Forge DevCon in Darmstadt, October '18, we were told that the server is the bottleneck for importing a scene and that a new server will be provided until November '18. The new server should increase the performance up to 15 times. 
Similar information can be found on the [Autodesk Beta Forums](https://beta.autodesk.com), where Cyrille Fauvel (Lead Developer) states the following:

- ''*Our preliminary test shows that the Unity plug-in load time is as
  fast as the Forge WEBGL viewer or faster.*''
- ''*Right now, the new server is on https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/. If you want to use it, please update your code accordingly. For the Unity plugin, you need to update the URL references into the ForgeLoaderConstants.cs #19 #20.*''

The problem is, that the there exist multiple different versions of the servers with different base-url's that host the AR/VR Toolkit:

- developer-api.autodesk.io (used as base url in unitypackage v3)
- developer-api-beta.autodesk.io (used as base url in unitypackage v6)
- developer-api-dev.autodesk.io (used as base url in a sample project that should access the new v2 server [ForgeToolkitSamples](https://github.com/wallabyway/forgetoolkitsamples))

As mentioned in the forums and stated above, the developer-api-beta.autodesk.io server should work but does not seem to work for us. We tried the following steps to make it work:

1. Create a new Bucket (we are EU based but tried everything with EMEA as well as US buckets)
2. Upload revit-file to bucket (Forge BaseUrl: developer.api.autodesk.com)
3. Translate to svf (Forge Base-Url: developer.api.autodesk.com)
4. Create Scene Definition (AR/VR Toolkit Base-Url)
5. Create Scene Job (AR/VR Toolkit Base-Url)
6. Unitypackage v6 using the AR/VR Toolkit Base-Url that we also used for creating scene job, together with UnityVersion (2018.2.19f1), loading on runtime as well as loading into the editor as asset.

**Results (for the different AR/VR Base-Url's we tried):**

For **developer-api-beta.autodesk.io**, the import worked for a very small scene, 3 walls and a chair. However, when we tried the same with a sample house, the import was as slow as ever and did no complete as we got a lot of 404 errors as well as one 504 error in the beginning.

We tried the steps above with **developer-api-dev.autodesk.io**, but couldn't get past step 5, as we couldn't get a manifest for the created scene job (creation worked). The exact same error (for the -beta url however) was reported by a user on November 23. on the chat (bottom right) available [here](http://forgetoolkit.com/#/).

We also tried unitypackage v6 together with **developer-api.autodesk.io**. The import didn't complete and ended with a lot of errors (404). It seemed like the loading of meshes and materials failed. We could see the scene tree in unity as well as the properties of the nodes, but no geometry.

On a legacy application, we are still using the unitypackage v3 of the importer together with that specific base-url (**developer-api.autodesk.io**) and it's working slow but stable and without errors.

---

We really tried a lot of other things for over a month but couldn't see the improved server performance.
Is there anyone that could possibly tell us if we are doing something wrong, or someone that can confirm that the server v2 (the faster one) is working for them?
Was the "new" server only available for a certain amount of time?

Also, it is very hard to keep track of all the changes happening to the AR/VR Toolkit, as one has to gather all the information from different sources such as official site, the Autodesk Beta Forums or the wallabyway Github. Another thing that is confusing is that a lot of the times in the beta forums, the new v2 server and the v1/v2 API are mentioned together, and it is not really clear on which URL they are published eventually.Also, on the [swaggerhub](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/2.0.0), where the documentation can be found, v2 API is marked as unpublished.

Comment: This is very thorough breakdown of the current state of the site - you are absolutely spot on.  Unfortunately, this is my fault and not getting on top of all the changes myself.  Let me put together a full response shortly.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Didn’t want to blame anybody, just wanted to know what is going on. I’m looking forward to the full response :-)

Comment: any update on this? @michaelbeale